# Should i have a primary ID? i am indexing another field

Tags: sql, database-design, primary-key, data-modeling

Using sqlite i need a table to hold a blob to store a md5 hash and a 4byte int. I plan to index the int but this value will not be unique.

Do i need a primary key for this table? and is there an issue with indexing a non unique value? (I assume there is not issue or reason for any).

Comment: +1.  Good question.  Personally, I like @Larry Lustig's answer better than my own.  His is relevant to sqllite, while mine is more of a general answer.

Answer (score 11):

Personally, I like to have a unique primary id on all tables.  It makes finding unique records for updating/deleting easier.

Comment: +1: Matches the ORM expectation of an immutable unique id for each row.

Comment: Except Many to Many link tables

Comment: @Alex: Actually, I like to have an extra id field on many-to-many link tables too. Sometimes it turns out to be useful to be able to print out the links in order of having been added, even if you originally though that it wouldn't matter, so an automatically incremented primary key is very useful. Also, when implementing delete functionality in an application (to remove the link), it is sometimes easier if you can refer to the row with a simple id.

Answer (score 3):

How are you going to reference on a `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE` or an `UPDATE ... WHERE`?  Are you sure you want each one?

Answer (score 3):

You already have one.

SQLite automatically creates an integer ROWID column for every row of every table.  This can function as a primary key if you don't declare your own.

In general it's a good idea to declare your own primary key column.  In the particular instance you mentioned, ROWID will probably be fine for you.

Comment: Thanks David.  I've only done one project using SQLite, but I really like it as a lightweight but still very, very capable DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to go with primary key if you want to have referential integrity. However  there is no issue with indexing a non unique value. The only thing is that your performance will downgrade a little.

Answer (score 1):

What are the consequences of letting two identical rows somehow get into this table?

One consequence is, of course, wasted space.  But I'm talking about something more fundamental, here.  There are times when duplicate rows in data give you wrong results.  For example, if you grouped by the int column (field), and listed the count of rows in each group,  a duplicate row (record) might throw you off, depending on what you are really looking for.

Relational databases work better if they are based on relations.  Relations are always in first normal form.  The primary reason for declaring a primary key is to prevent the table from getting out of first normal form, and thus not representing a relation.